# PyZipper returning "Bad password for file" with the right password

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I was coding a software which was going to bruteforce a file named `"Blockers password.zip"`, using the given passwords (reading line by line [each line has its password]) in the `"Passwords.txt"` file.

The thing is, I was getting the error `"Bad password for file"` with the ZipFile module, then I made some search and realized that the ZipFile module doesn't support the AES encryption (the PyZipper does), so I was not able to decrypt the file with it, now, using the PyZipper and I'm getting the same error and I don't know why...

The content of the `"Passwords.txt`" file:
https://prnt.sc/rueuf1

Here is the code.

```
import pyzipper

name_file = 'Passwords.txt'

# This file contains all the generated passwords
# for bruteforcing the file which has
# my blockers password
passwords_for_bruteforce = open(name_file, 'r')

# My goal here is use every password in the 'Passwords.txt' file
# to do a bruteforce on the 'Blockers password.zip'
# but it can't be bruteforced because of the "RuntimeError: Bad password for file"
# and the correct password is in the last line of the 'Passwords.txt'
for line in passwords_for_bruteforce:
    password = line.rstrip('\n')
    with pyzipper.AESZipFile('Blockers password.zip', 'r') as zip_file:
        zip_file.pwd = password
        zip_file.extractall()
passwords_for_bruteforce.close()
```

Comment: you need to put a `try/except` block around the code that throws the exception.

Comment: Thank you Todd, I used a try+except+continue(in except block) and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to brute force it. This means you need to handle wrong passwords otherwise the first password must be right or it will throw your error.
As @Todd said a try/except block should solve the problem:

```
for line in passwords_for_bruteforce:       
    password = line.rstrip('\n')
    with pyzipper.AESZipFile('Blockers password.zip', 'r') as zip_file:
        try:
            zip_file.pwd = password 
            zip_file.extractall()
         except RuntimeError:
            continue
```

IMHO you could also open the file once and try to extract it multiple times. This will save you some IO operations.

```
with pyzipper.AESZipFile('Blockers password.zip', 'r') as zip_file:
    for line in passwords_for_bruteforce:       
        zip_file.pwd = line.rstrip('\n')
        try:
            zip_file.extractall()
        except RuntimeError:
            continue
```

Comment: Hello! I thought in the use of a try and except block but for some reason I didn't test it. Sorry for being late, yesterday I tested this solution and it worked like a charm.

Comment: But I should use the try and except block ALWAYS in these cases where I want to bruteforce something? But in another case, like, in the case of just decrypting the file with the right password, it would give me the same error, right? So is there another way to fix that without using the try and except?

Comment: @BRKappa Bruteforcing is based on failing many times to get one success. So you **always** need to handle wrong password errors. Normally this error should only appear when using the wrong password, so you won't need to handle it when using the right password. To catch errors in python there's only the try/except method.